# Number of ways to select $r$ objects from $n$ objects placed on the circumference of a circle

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Prove using combinatorial argument that number of ways to select $r$ objects from $n$ distinct objects such that no two selected objects are consecutively placed on the circumference of a circle is $$\frac{n}{n-r} \binom{n-r}{r}.$$

I am aware that number of ways to do so is $$\frac{n}{r}\binom{n-r-1}{r-1}.$$ But I would want to understand how $$\frac{n}{n-r} \binom{n-r}{r}$$ comes combinatorially. I think it has something to do with menage problem.

Comment: If $r > n/2$, then your formula gives zero.   For instance, if $n = 3$ and $r = 2$, your formula gives $3\binom{1}{2} = 0$.

Comment: Why would placing the objects on a circle affect the number of ways of selecting the objects?

Comment: Your formulas do not make sense.  Please check the wording of the question.

Comment: You are right. I am editing.

Comment: In my response to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2404157/how-many-subsets-of-size-k-exist-such-that-no-pair-of-elements-is-r/2404430#2404430), I explain how to derive a formula for the number of selections of $k$ objects from $n$ objects arranged in a circle if no two of the $k$ objects are consecutive.  With a bit of algebraic manipulation (using Pascal's Identity) of the formula I derived, you can derive the formula $$\frac{n}{k}\binom{n - k - 1}{k - 1}$$ and then show it is equivalent to the formula $$\frac{n}{n - k}\binom{n - k}{k}$$

Comment: @N.F.Taussig. I wanted a combinatorical explanation. To me it appears that first (n-k) objects are placed and then from the (n-k) gaps on the circle we choose k gaps in $\binom{n-k}{k}$ ways. But how to explain it especially the n in the numerator and n-k in the denominator

Comment: My answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3680829/3736) gives a combinatorial interpretation.

Comment: I've realized that perhaps a bit more explanation is needed, so I've added an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let the objects be placed on the vertices of an $n$-gon. You ask how many ways are there to select $r$ of the objects such that no two selected objects are consecutive.

Your problem is equivalent to the problem of placing $r$ non-overlapping dominoes on the vertices of an $n$-gon. (Each domino covers two vertices.) To map the domino problem to your problem, let the object sitting on vertex $i$ be one of the selected ones. Then place one of the dominoes so that it covers vertices $i$ and $i+1$, with $i+1$ computed mod $n$. The condition that no two selected objects be consecutive is equivalent to the condition that the dominoes be non-overlapping.

We may then apply the solution given in my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3680829/3736) to the domino formulation of the problem. Briefly, let $D$ represent a domino and let $V$ represent a bare vertex (one not covered by a domino). There are $r$ $D$s and $n-2r$ $V$s on our circle. The factor $\binom{n-r}{r}$ in your expression is the number of words one can make with these letters. Each such word may be wrapped on the circle in $n$ ways. But this overcounts domino configurations by a factor of $n-r$ since each of the $n-r$ cyclic permutations of the letters of a word gives rise to the same domino configurations.

Incidentally, the connection with the *ménage* problem is that the expression $\frac{2n}{2n-r}\binom{2n-r}{r}$ appears in the Touchard formula for the number of configurations:
$$
2\cdot n!\sum_{r=0}^n(-1)^r\frac{2n}{2n-r}\binom{2n-r}{r}(n-r)!.
$$
Domino configurations have been used to enumerate unwanted configurations that need to be excluded in an inclusion-exclusion argument. See [this article](https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.04115).