# Derangement after derangement

Tags: derangements

*n* people can be seated on *n* chairs in *n*! different ways. These are *permutations*.

If the people get up and sit down again in such a way that nobody sits on the same chair they sat on before, this can be done in !*n* different ways. These are [*derangements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement).

Now, if the people get up and sit down again in such a way that nobody sits on a chair they have sat on before, the number of possibilities depends on the choice in the previous step.

For example, with *n=4*:

First seating: ABCD
Second seating: BADC
Possible third seatings: CDAB CDBA DCAB DCBA, a total of 4.

First seating: ABCD
Second seating: BCDA
Possible third seatings: CDAB DABC, a total of 2.

As far as I can determine,
with four objects, the number of possible third seatings is either 2 or 4, and
with five objects, the number of possible third seatings is either 12 og 13.

Is there a formula for (or can anything intelligent be said about) the number of possible third (and fourth, and fifth ...) seatings?

Comment: Related question: What is the probability that a randomly-selected derangement of a randomly-selected derangement is still a derangement of the original set? In other words, if everybody gets up and sits down in a different chair and then does that again, what is the chance that no one is sitting in their original chair?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3674756/double-derangement-and-the-other-unfamous-kind-of-derangement?rq=1

Comment: Bruteforce gives that for 6 it's 80 or 82, for 7 it's 578, 579 or 580, for 8 - 4738, 4740, 4744 or 4752.