# Definition of limit points, equivalence and its negation

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, solution-verification

The definition (from my book) we take is:

> $x$ is a limit point of $(x_n)$ if $\exists$ a subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ of $(x_n)$ so that $\lim_{k \to \infty} x_{n_k} = x $

Now, this how I understand equivalences to this definition and its negation:

${\bf I.}$  $x$ is limit point of $(x_n)$ if $\forall \epsilon >0$ $\exists\ N > 0$ so that $k > N$ implies $|x_{n_k} - x | < \epsilon $.

${\bf II}.$ If we put put $X = \{ x_n : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ if for any $\epsilon > 0$, we have infinitely many of the $x_n's$ lying in $B_{\epsilon}(x)$

Now, these are equivalent to the definition of a limit point.

The negation would be: $x$ is ${\bf not}$ a limit point if $\exists\ \epsilon >0$ such that for all $N > 0$ one can find $k > N$ so that $|x_{n_k} - x| \geq \epsilon $

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes. I ve used this many times

Comment: ${\bf I.}$  Does not make sense. What is $x_{n_k}$ in this statement?

Comment: IT is a  subsequence

Comment: That is not a proper definition of limit point.

Comment: Kavi: Well, that is why I am asking here. I wrote my understanding, and I Wanted to see whether I am understanding it correctly. What would then be a proper definition of limit point?

Comment: @James: Sahiba Arora’s answer has a nice, careful version of what you were trying for. The main problem with yours is that you never actually mentioned the subsequence: its element $x_{n_k}}$ just suddenly appears out of nowhere. Insert ‘$(x_n)$ has a subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ such that ’ after ‘if’, and you’ve have a less careful but still adequate version of Sahiba Arora’s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

${\bf II}.$ seems right but ${\bf I}.$ needs to be modified as follows:

${\bf I'}. x $ is a limit point of $(x_n)$ if there exists a sequence $(n_k)_k$ in $\mathbb{N}$ such that $n_k \to \infty$ and for each $\epsilon>0,$ there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $k>N$ implies $|x_{n_k}-x|<\epsilon.$

The negation would also need to tweaked as follows:

$x$ is not a limit point of $(x_n$) if for every sequence $(n_k)_k$ in $\mathbb{N}$ with $n_k \to \infty,$ there exists $\epsilon >0$ such that for every $N \in \mathbb{N},$ there exists $k>N$ with $|x_{n_k}-x|\geq \epsilon.$